# Limiting number of checkboxes selected in gridview in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I need limiting the number of checkboxes selected by user on the GridView in c# asp net.

I tried the code below but I have two problems:

1. After alert popup **`'Cannot check more than 3 check boxes'`** the Checkbox number four is always selected;
2. The button **`btn`** is enabled and validate the form.

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckCheck() {
            var chkBoxList = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');
            var chkBoxCount = chkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");

            var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>');
            var i = 0;
            var tot = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++) {
                if (chkBoxCount[i].checked) {
                    tot = tot + 1;
                }
            }

            if (tot > 3) {
                alert('Cannot check more than 3 check boxes');
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelProduct" runat="server" onclick="javascript:CheckCheck();" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("name")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="250px" DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Send" OnClick="btn_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck the 4th checked checkbox:

```
function CheckCheck()
{
    var chkBoxList = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');
    var chkBoxCount = chkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var btn = document.getElementById('<%=btn.ClientID %>');
    var i = 0;
    var tot = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < chkBoxCount.length; i++)
    {
        if (chkBoxCount[i].checked)
        {
            tot = tot + 1;

            if (tot > 3)
            {
                alert('Cannot check more than 3 check boxes');
                chkBoxCount[i].checked = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```